# Encode Unicode to iso8859-15 with Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, encode, iso-8859-15

I am using Python 2.7.6 and I am trying to convert a basic unicode string to iso8859-15.

I get an error when trying to convert an string with non-ASCII chars. This would be ok, when those chars would not exist is the iso8859-15 coding but in this case they do:

Example:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> a = "test"
>>> a
'test'
>>> a.encode ('iso8859-15')
'test'
>>> a = "ü"
>>> a
'\xfc'
>>> a.encode ('iso8859-15')
```

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    a.encode ('iso8859-15')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_15.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In this case `"ü"` is a valid iso8859-15 char with the hex-value fc or a 11111100 as binary.
Looking in "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_15.py" there is the value FC in line 300:

```
    47:  decoding_table = (
    48:  u'\x00'     #  0x00 -> NULL
    .....
    300: u'\xfc'     #  0xFC -> LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
```

How can I convert unicode strings with non-ascii chars like "ü" into 'iso8859-15'?
If the function encode does not work in this case: How can I import the encoding_table list in lib\encodings\iso8859_15.py directly into my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to encode a *byte string*. The bytestring is already encoded, so Python tries to first **decode** it for you so that can then encode it again, and it'll use ASCII to do that.

The exception reflects this; you got an `UnicodeDecodeError`, not `UnicodeEncodeError`.

To create unicode values, use `u'...'` unicode literals instead:

```
>>> a = u'ü'
>>> a
u'\xfc'
>>> a.encode('iso8859-15')
'\xfc'
```

or decode your bytestring data to Unicode using a valid encoding:

```
>>> a = 'ü'
>>> a.decode('utf8')  # my terminal is configured to use UTF-8
u'\xfc'
>>> a.decode('utf8').encode('iso8859-15')
'\xfc'
```